# Hosting ASP pages on OSX using Mono that have virtual includes

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, asp-classic, mono

I'm working on making Mono work on a Mac and (for the most part) it is except for when I am running pages that use virtual includes. I have tried using both the XSP (XSP, XSP2, and XSP4) server as well as configuring Apache but haven't succeeded in either to make the pages show.

The code in the ASP page is as follows:

```
<!--#include virtual="/wrapper/wrapper-home-top.asp" -->
<!-- START: PAGE CONTENT -->
<!--#include virtual="/assets/home/home.html" -->
<!-- END: PAGE CONTENT -->
<!--#include virtual="/wrapper/wrapper-bottom.asp" -->
```

This is also what I'm seeing in the web browser instead of the content. So it seems like the server is serving the page but not processing it.

Does anyone have an example of the proper configurations to demonstrate this functioning? Or is this not supported and I should try another means of viewing these in-browser?

Comment: Mono does not support classic asp.